# Handling users that visit a PHP process page without POST

Tags: php, ajax, security, user-interface

This question addresses the security / user end side of things.

Suppose I have a script that is called via ajax which will add something to a database.

The script checks for the request method. If it is from 'POST' then the script will carry out this function.

I do not want users accessing my pages and either getting an error or a blank page.

What is the 'ideal' way to deal with this?

My current plan is as follows: If it is not a POST method, redirect them to an error page in the same way as a 404 handler and then provide some links for elsewhere.

Comment: I would redirect to your standard 404 page; if you think about it the page *doesn't* exits for that request method. Or you could use (error 405)

Comment: ah okay, i just didnt like the idea of error pages, but at the end of the day the user shouldnt be going there and expecting anything anyway. I think ill 404 them thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning a 400 Bad Request is a pretty standard way to indicate that the user got there without the proper data that's needed.

```
if(!isset($_POST)){
  header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
}
```

On top of that, you should spend some time investigating doing some cross site request forgery protection (CSRF) if you want to make sure only your UI posts to that page.

Comment: thanks, i shall give that a go. Yeah i have a lot of testing around to find loop holes and errors that give a bad UX so will be doing all of that. I shall have a look into CSRF as its a knew acronym for me.

Comment: @justin_kiang the 'HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request' doesnt do anything. Any ideas why? im on mamp if thats anything to do with it?

Comment: It is simply a header telling the browser that the request is bad.  It is up to the browser to show different UI.  Some browser just shows a blank page, some shows a sad face, some shows a funny message.  If you want a customized page to show, you need to also say `header("location: friendly_error_page.php")`

Comment: PS, I can directly access your file from another anywhere on the web should I choose to call it through an action of post. i can even set it on my computer and call your file and it would access it as long as I called it with post method in a form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i use it in all my pages called via ajax:

```
if ($_POST['ajax'] == "ajax") { // You need to set this is your post ajax variables sent to this php file.
    // all your code here
} else {
    // Not needed for a blank page, or whatever you want for another page ie
    header ("location: 404.php");
}
```

Comment: You didn't define `ajax`

Comment: @mike, please do not comment like this if you have not read the entire answer, I specifically mentioned in my answer that she needs to set it in her ajax variables sent to this page. Not knowing what her code is for ajax, and every code could be different even slightly,.

Comment: Well, you edited your answer to include quotes around `"ajax"` so now it's a string.

Comment: seems the general rule is 404, i shall do it that way. thanks :)

Comment: @user2921557 No, not 404, but 400.